# Change a database table name using Entity Framework code first migrations

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-migrations

How would you change the names of your tables using Entity Frameworks code first migrations.

The below code, creates my tables as :

RoleBindingModel, DivisionBindingModel etc. and that's not ideal.

How would you change the name to a custom table name? (Without changing your models name)

IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<RoleBindingModel> Role { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DivisionBindingModel> Division { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CategoryBindingModel> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductBindingModel> Product { get; set; }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

[image: Table names]

Comment: you mean in runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is by using DataAnnotations and the `Table` attribute.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;    

[Table("Role")]
public class RoleBindingModel
{

}
```